# Can I show borders on a TextBox in Avalonia while the TextBox is Disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm creating a series of Textboxes from the code-behind in order to have a variable amount of controls based on data being passed in, however I wish to be able to have the TextBox disabled so that the user can't click on them, while still having a border on each of the Textboxes.

```
dateHeaderTextBox.BorderBrush = Brushes.White;
dateHeaderTextBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
```

Essentially the control will ignore this code and not draw the border if I have set the textbox to be disabled like so:

```
dateHeaderTextBox.IsEnabled = false;
```

Just for reference I also tried setting the style within the .axaml document like so:

```
<UserControl.Styles>
    <Style Selector="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Styles>
```

But the border still seems to not draw. I'm not sure if that's because I'm creating the control from the code-behind or because the Textbox is set to being disabled.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you are using fluent theme you have to modify the `TextBox /template/ Border#PART_BorderElement` part instead. Here you can  see how the textbox template looks like: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Fluent/Controls/TextBox.xaml#L188

Comment: Okay I will take a look at this and see if I can get it to work